# pandas groupby ignoring NAs

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a DataFrame which has a lot of NAs.  pandas's groupby operation is ignoring any combinations with NA in it.  Is there a way to include NAs in groups?  If not, what are the alternatives to pandas groupby?  I really don't want to fill in NAs because the fact that something is missing is useful information.

Edit: I noticed that my question is exactly the same issue reported in [groupby columns with NaN (missing) values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18429491/groupby-columns-with-nan-missing-values)
Has there been any developments technology to get around this issue?

Comment: The question is a bit vague. Could you please show what you tried and what is your desired output?

Answer (score 1):

I will use some kind of non-NA representation for NA only for groupby, which can't be confused with proper data (e.g. -999999 or 'missing')

```
df.fillna(-999999).groupby(...)
```

As `inplace` argument has default value `False` your original dataframe will not be affected.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Will df.fillna(-999999) work if my df has mixed data types such as string, float, datetime, etc.?

Comment: I've just tested it and it shouldn't be a problem for grouped columns.